# Having issue with CSS hover with different hover size

Tags: hover, css

Now what I am doing is having a text nav but then on hover still keeping the text but using an image as the background.

Because the text is varying sizes & the background image is one size it's becoming a problem because I only have 597px to work within for the nav area & I also want the same amount of spacing between each nav selection.

I want this for example..

[image]

But currently I am getting this:

[image]

The nav background image is 87px in width, so obviously it's wrapping because we don't have enough space. But we also end up with varying amounts of space between each nav item because each is set to 87px.

So I was wondering if there was any clean way to do what I want without using javascript & without the nav items jumping around when hovering over others?

I've tried putting differing widths on the different states but the nav just jumped around & looked terrible.

Any idea to do what I'm wanting?

If you would like to see my current HTML & CSS it's below:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav_wrapper">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="our_process.php">OUR PROCESS</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.php">OUR WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="free_quote.php">FREE QUOTE</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_us.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Nav Ends -->
    <div class="contentClear"></div>
</div>
<!-- Nav Wrapper Ends -->
```

CSS:

```
#header .nav_wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 597px;
    margin: 30px 0 0 50px;
}

#header .nav_wrapper .nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none;
}

#header .nav_wrapper li {
    float: left;
    height: 23px;
    min-width: 87px;
    font-family: "Zurich Cn BT", Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.nav li a, ul.nav li a:visited, ul.nav li a:focus {
    display: block;
    line-height: 23px;
    color: #764422;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.nav li a:hover, ul.nav li a:active {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url(../images/nav-bg.png);
}
```

Comment: do you want your menu centered?

Comment: use two images for background image one big button expanding to right and 1 left rounded corner...add span tag with a tag or use li for second image..

Comment: @Hristo No, not the whole thing. Just each nav button within the background image.

Comment: @Yasir OK.... I think I know what you mean & I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what i would do is to style each `<li>`'s width to the size of the background image (i.e. 87px). If space does become a problem, then I would create a few different background images (e.g. 70px, 87px and 95px) and set the width of their respective `<li>`s accordingly. it's a simple solution that works well and doesn't add any js complication.

Comment: I have thought of that & may have to go that route if necessary. :)

Answer (score 2):

Are images required? If not, you could try using CSS3 (or filter for ie as a  fallback):

```
  background-color: #FCC051;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FCC051, #FAA200); /* FF3.6 */
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FCC051, #FAA200); /* IE10 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FCC051, #FAA200); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FCC051), to(#FAA200)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FCC051, #FAA200); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FCC051, #FAA200);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FCC051', EndColorStr='#FAA200'); /* IE6–IE9 */
```

Example can be found here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/7X3qw/2/

Unless you need to support >IE6, this should work. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that..... definitely an option if nothing else works out with the images.

Comment: Well, personally, I would use an image sprite containing gradients of different widths as the absolute fallback. Frankly, some people don't want to upgrade a browser if they already like what they've got. Even MS Paint can create different sizes for that gradient without distorting the rounded corners. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your fix, just insert your background image 
http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/7zELD/

```
background: url('path here') center center no-repeat transparent;
```

I am equal spacing the size of each li using a percentage 1/8 of the total size

Comment: Thanks..... but I'm not sure what else to change in my CSS to get it to work. I tried looking at your example CSS code but nothing seemed to work for my situation.

Comment: #header .nav_wrapper li a{
    float: left;
    height: 23px;
    width: 12.5%;
    font-family: "Zurich Cn BT", Tahoma;
    font-size: 10px;

}

Comment: Doesn't work..... that ends up wrapping each nav element. Perhaps I will have to give different sizes to each one.

Comment: @Brett the issue is that the size of each li item when added together is > the total width of the container, you should just copy and paste my css rules in from the link into your code and add the images.. it should work  here is an updated link with images used for the background http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/7zELD/4/

Comment: That's fine. The font will need to shrink to fit in the area and you also are going to have to change the image size to fit the size of the li